# Computation of average number of hops for an atom reach a certain distance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, robust-statistics

I apologize if this has been asked before. I tried searching all previous posts to look at different forms of this problem (such as random 2d walks on a lattice, relation to Isling's work, etc.). I posted this question to statistical physics section but I hope this is more relevant for this thread.

The problem is as follows (same as a random walk from the origin on a 2D lattice): there is an atom at the 2D cartesian origin (0,0) and hops in equal likelihood to all four directions. Understandably, the 2D joint distribution of the final coordinates $(x,y)$ after $N$ steps can be modeled through either a multinomial, or matrix convolution approach. I am trying to estimate the average number of hops it takes to reach a certain distance $d$.

I was able to decipher from numerous sources (including the original Whipple,McCrea paper that discussed the 2d random walk problem in detail) that the expected average number of hops is $ \approx d^2 $.

In order to show this, I attempted to compute the discrete probability mass function for the random variable $R_d$, defined as the number of steps it takes before it reaches distance $d$. For e.g., $P_{R_d}(R_d = r; d=10) = P_{x,y}(x_{(r)}^2 + y_{(r)}^2 \geq d^2 \text{ and } x_{(r-1)}^2 + y_{(r-1)}^2 < d^2 \text{ and } x_{(r-2)}^2 + y_{(r-2)}^2 < d^2 \cdots)$

where $x_{(r)},y_{(r)}$ are the coordinates at the $r$th step.

I tried simulating these with independent random samples and got expectations that go as $d^2 + \frac{d}{2}$, not $d^2$.

I am trying to estimate with certain precision $\tau$ and show that even when given the joint distribution on $x_{(i)},y_{(i)}$, we get $d^2$.

What would the best way be to estimate this expectation? Should I use MCMC methods, like Metropolis Hastings method? Would I set it up $R$ dependent on samples taken randomly from the distribution $p_{x,y}(x,y)$.

Comment: Asymptotically, $d^2\sim d^2+d$. You can also inductively show that $E(x_n^2+y_n^2)=n$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! You gave a very elegant solution. I understand that asymptotically that $d^2 \approx d^2 +d$. Suppose instead we are not in the asymptotic limit and want a near-exact expectation on $R$ with precision $\tau$ digits in the range of say $d = 80$ or $100$. Since this would require too many simulations to get an accurate estimate for the expectation, would a MCMC be a better approximate inference method:?

Comment: Here is a dumb way to find an exact answer. Let $T(x,y)$ be expected time to reach radius $r$ starting at $(x,y)$. Then for $|(x,y)|<r$, $T(x,y)=1+\frac 1 4\sum_{(x,y)\to(x',y')} T(x',y')$ and $T(x,y)=0$ if $|(x,y)|\ge r$. You can also restrict yourself to the first quadrant using symmetry. You are left with a linear system in $v\approx\frac\pi 4 r^2$ variables which you can solve  in $\frac 2 3 v^3+O(v^2)$ time.

Comment: Thank you @A.S. That answers my question perfectly!

Comment: Good to hear that. You can even further half the number of variables by considering symmetry across the diagonal and hence reduce total time by a factor of 8.